# Como averiguar en que formato o codificación esta un archivo javascript?

Tags: javascript, base64, unicode

esoty intentatndo decodificar un archivo que yo creía que era base64 pero como al decodificarlo obtengo informacion sin sentido me parecía que no era base 64 sino otra cosa.

El archivo es de tipo sscript:

abcd({"data":"c23pTGxuYzZv5ElmNf04A2dSalQ3c...................................="})

Y bueno quería saber si hay alguna forma de saber exactamente en que codificación está.

Edito la pregunta a ver si se entiende mejor, si tengo una imagen png en base 64 y sabiendo que es una imagen png entrando en una pagina para tranformar de base 64 a imagen como https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter PEGO EL CODIGO Y OBTENGO UNA IMAGEN. En cambio si a este mismo codigo lo pego en otra pagina que es solo para decodificar base 64 como https://www.base64decode.org/ OBTENGO UN CODIGO SIN SENTIDO.

COMO POR EJEMPLO:
PNG

IHDR    m"HPLTE}}))55NNbb^^==xxBB,,HHVViiRRpp[[pcIDATx흇z0   Vp:Zv
$ 1$H8Ȳy,+IK4>P8,֑^|tAP3kc߆p,j*b84{0Z,p@!c~XlcL:w\6'$ICx":DcF.*b佽܃_!8 xYv1$`h7zw7_킡v%̲:Z.............................................

En cambio si yo quiero convertir base 64 a json hay alguna página que lo haga?
Creo qe es Json porque el mime type cuando se solicita este archivo al servidor es "aplication/javascript" en cambio cuando se solicita una imagen es jpeg o png.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Sabes qué tipo de información debería guardar? Si es un fichero binario es normal que al decodificarlo parezca información sin sentido

Comment: Hola @Pablo Lozano, debería ser aplication/javascipt

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el método atob() https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob
para intentar decodificarla. Si te da un DOMException, es que no es un múltiplo de 4, como explica la documentación.

Que al decodificarlo obtengas información sin sentido no garantiza que no sea base64. Va a depender de la codificación de la cadena (ASCII, Unicode, etc), lo que obtengas. La codificación puede ser de una imagen, por ejemplo, también, con lo cual lo que obtendrías no tiene por que estar en un idioma legible.

No hay ninguna forma standard de saber la codificación de una cadena. Lo único otro que puedes hacer es testearla con diferentes expresiones regulares que se ajusten a cada tipo de codificación, mediante regex.test('tu_cadena')